# Can we sort arguments then save to the indexes accordingly?

Tags: bash, sorting, scripting, arguments

Hi first of all I'm fairly new in bash scripting, basically 1 day of knowledge so far

I'm trying to sort the arguments passed from the bash, yes I managed to do that but when I try to display my arguments afterwards, the arguments are not sorted, why ?

```
printf "%s\n" $@ | sort -n
```

This will sort the numbers then display it, but **can I save those
   numbers to their indexes accordingly** ?

What I mean is, with `./task.sh 9 0 5` 
the code above would display `0 5 9`, but if I try to display $1 $2 $3 after that
I would get `9 0 5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# save stdout of your pipe in variable $foo
foo=$(printf "%s\n" $@ | sort -n)

# assign arguments after -- to the positional parameters
set -- $foo

echo $1 $2 $3
```

Output:

```
0 5 9
```

Comment: Beautiful, what does the -- means though ?

Comment: It's part of `set`'s syntax. You can set or unset values of shell options and set positional parameters ($1, $2, $3 ...) with `set`. See: `help set` or with man page style: `help -m set | less`.

Comment: That reference is really helpful, thanks once again Cyrus !!